# Print a value from a nested dictionary if a prior condition is true

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

The goal here is to print out the student id's for all student's that have an average assignment score of over 2.0. Right now when I run the code, it just prints False for every student that has an average over 2.0. What am I missing? I've tried rearranging the order to no avail. Also, changing the format of the dictionary is not an option here.

EDIT - OK first bit has been solved and I've updated the code. Now, how do I make my final output of student id's into a list? I tried defining identify and then printing in list form, but that just returns multiple individual lists, not all of the results in one list.

```
students = {"student_1": {"id":12,"Assignments":[("Assignment_1",3),("Assignment_2", 4), ("Assignment_3", 2)]},
            "student_2" :{"id":13,"Assignments":[("Assignment_1",2),("Assignment_2", 4), ("Assignment_3", 2)]},
            "student_3" :{"id":14,"Assignments":[("Assignment_1",0),("Assignment_2", 1), ("Assignment_3", 1)]}}
```

Loop:

```
for student in students.values():
        scores = [score for (assignment, score) in student["Assignments"]]
        identify = int(student["id"])
        if sum(scores)/len(scores) >=2.0:
            print([identify])
```

Comment: `print(student['id'])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very good! The problem is in your last line. You're checking:

```py
"id" in students.values())
```

Here's `student.values()` as a list:

```
["student_1": {"id":12,"Assignments":[("Assignment_1",3),("Assignment_2", 4), ("Assignment_3", 2)]},
"student_2" :{"id":13,"Assignments":[("Assignment_1",2),("Assignment_2", 4), ("Assignment_3", 2)]},
"student_3" :{"id":14,"Assignments":[("Assignment_1",0),("Assignment_2", 1), ("Assignment_3", 1)]}]
```

Let's take a second to evaluate what that statement does. To simplify, we'll use:

```
a = 5
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(a in b)
```

This code can also be written

```
for x in b:
    if a == x:
        print(True)
print(False)
```

Right now, you're checking if the string `"id"` is in the list of nested dictionaries. It's not! Instead, you want to access the `"id"` key in your `student` dictionary:

```
student["id"]
```

Putting it altogether:

```
print(student["id"])
```

And then the full code:

```
for student in students.values():
        scores = [score for (assignment, score) in student["Assignments"]]
        if sum(scores)/len(scores) >=2.0:
            print(student["id"])
```

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for walking through it. It's very helpful for me to see where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code `print("id" in students.values())` prints boolean because you are testing if `students.values()` contains 'id' or not. It returns boolean and because  of `students.values` doesn't contain 'id', it prints false. You need to change that line of code to `print(student['id'])` in order to print 'id'.

Comment: That was a lot simpler than I imagined. Thanks for the explanation.